# Can someone tell me what is wrong here? I want to return the vegetable array in CAPITAL letters

Tags: javascript

```js
let vegetables = ["cucumbers", "carrots", "tomatoes"];
let upperCase = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= vegetables.length; i++) {
    vegetables[i].toUpperCase();
  }
  return vegetables[i];
};
console.log(upperCase());
```

Comment: A single byte is the culprit. `i <= vegetables.length` should be `i < vegetables.length`. Remember: array **indexes start at 0**, while array length gives the **amount of items** inside the given array.

Comment: Also `const uCase = ["cucumbers", "carrots", "tomatoes"].map(veg => veg.toUpperCase())`

Comment: Strings are immutable, so it should be `vegetables[i] = vegetables[i].toUpperCase()` if you want to use a for loop

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think it's right to change any code in a post, as it will change the situation the OP is in. Why don't you just flag the question and add your helpful comments?

Comment: Very well........

Answer (score 1):

I think toUpperCase() method returns a string value, not changes yours, so you need to do like this
`vegetables[i] = vegetables[i].toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 1):

```
let vegetables = ["cucumbers", "carrots", "tomatoes"];

let upperCase = function(){
    return vegetables.map( vegetable => vegetable.toUpperCase())
}

console.log(upperCase()); // [ 'CUCUMBERS', 'CARROTS', 'TOMATOES' ]
```

// OR YOU CAN ALSO DO THE SAME WITH THIS

```
let vegetables = ["cucumbers", "carrots", "tomatoes"];

let upperCase = () => vegetables.map( vegetable => vegetable.toUpperCase())

console.log(upperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `vegetables[i].toUpperCase()` does not replace the array value, upperCase does not work "in place"
2. You need to return the result if you choose to `console.log(upperCase())`
   instead of doing `upperCase(); console.log(vegetables)`
3. You overrun the array with your `<=` - it should be `<` since arrays are zero based.

Here is your FIXED version

```js
let vegetables = ["cucumbers", "carrots", "tomatoes"];
let upperCase = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < vegetables.length; i++) {
    vegetables[i] = vegetables[i].toUpperCase();
  }
  return vegetables;
};
console.log(upperCase());
```

and here is a version for 2022

```js
const upperCase = arr => arr.map(item => item && typeof item === 'string' ? item.toUpperCase() : item)
let vegetables = ["cucumbers", "carrots", "tomatoes"];


console.log(upperCase(vegetables));
```

Breakdown

```
const upperCase // name of method  
= arr // passing something we call arr  
=>    // arrow function - note we do not need "{ return ... }" if there is only one processing statement  
arr.map(   // return a map (array) of the passed array, e.g. do not modify the passed array   
item => // each element is processed as item  
item && typeof item === 'string' // if item is not falsy and is a string  
? item.toUpperCase() // return item uppercased  
: item) // else return the item (this construct is called a ternary)
```

Comment: Very nice breakdown. Awesome. Please consider adding how the `return` for the method is implicit, if you think it adds value. So, instead of `arr => { return arr.map(....); }`, one is simply able to use `arr => arr.map(....);`.

Comment: Good idea. Added

Answer (score 0):

```
let vegetables = ["cucumbers", "carrots", "tomatoes"];

let upperCase = function() {
    let lst=[]
  for (let i = 0; i < vegetables.length; i++) {
    lst.push(vegetables[i].toUpperCase());
  }
  return lst
  
};

console.log(upperCase());
```

works this code :)

In for loop should iterate till i< vegetables.length. If not we try to convert uppercase, undefined thing. Then we get error

Comment: _If not we try to convert uppercase, undefined thing. Then we get error_ You mean the `<=` overruns the array trying to upperCase something outside the array

Comment: yes. <= overruns the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 Array Methods

```js
let vegetables = ["cucumbers", "carrots", "tomatoes"];

let upperCase = vegetables.map(el => el.toUpperCase());

console.log(upperCase);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).